# C# XML Serialisation - Namespace Issue with referenced Schema

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm serialising class to specific XML format.  Below is the class structure & code I've used to serialize it. Serailized file tend to miss element name "Address".

I've 3 classes StudentInfo which has two properties of type "Student" & "Address"

```
[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("StudentInfo", Namespace = "http://TestBizTalkMap.Student")]
public class StudentInfo
{
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("", Namespace = "")]
     public Student Student { get; set; }

     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ns1", Namespace = "ns1:http://TestBizTalkMap.Address")]

      public Address Address { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public string EnrollNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BTSReceivedOn { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Address", Namespace = "http://TestBizTalkMap.Address")]
public class Address
{
    [XmlElement("",Namespace="")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("", Namespace = "")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Code Used to serialze it:

```
public XmlDocument GetXMLSchema<T>(T type, string schemeNameSpace)
{
   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type.GetType());
   try
     {
          using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
          {
              XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
              ns.Add("ns0", schemeNameSpace);
              xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, type, ns);
              xmlStream.Position = 0;
              xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
              if (xmlDoc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
              {
                    xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
              }
           }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw ex;
     }
            return xmlDoc;
     }
```

it serializes it to as

```
<ns0:StudentInfo xmlns:ns0="http://TestBizTalkMap.Student">
<Student>
<EnrollNo>EnrollNl</EnrollNo>
<Name>Name</Name>
<BTSReceivedOn>BTSReceivedOn</BTSReceivedOn>
</Student>

<ns1  xmlns="http://TestBizTalkMap.Address">
<City>City</City>
<State>State</State>
</ns1>
</ns0:StudentInfo
```

Whereas I want it to get serialised as

```
<ns0:StudentInfo xmlns:ns0="http://TestBizTalkMap.Student">
  <Student>
    <EnrollNo>EnrollNo_0</EnrollNo>
    <Name>Name_0</Name>
    <BTSReceivedOn>BTSReceivedOn_0</BTSReceivedOn>
  </Student>

 <ns1:Adress xmlns:ns1="http://TestBizTalkMap.Address">
    <City>City_0</City>
    <State>State_0</State>
  </ns1:Adress>
</ns0:StudentInfo>
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing `XmlElement("ns1", Namespace = "...")` to `XmlElement("Address", Namespace = "...")` on the Address property ? Seems pretty obvious but thought I'd check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have got awfully confused between names and namespaces. The name of your `Address` element is `Address`, not `ns1`, and its namespace is `http://TestBizTalkMap.Address`, not `ns1:http://TestBizTalkMap.Address`.

This is all you need to generate the correct XML.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://TestBizTalkMap.Student")]
public class StudentInfo
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://TestBizTalkMap.Address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string EnrollNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BTSReceivedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{    
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string City { get; set; }        
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

The namespace *prefixes* are unimportant, but if you really want them to be `ns0` and `ns1` then you can specify these via the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` you pass to the `Serialize` method:

```
var ns= new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("ns0", "http://TestBizTalkMap.Student");
ns.Add("ns1", "http://TestBizTalkMap.Address");
```

And if you don't want the XML Declaration, then *don't* load the resulting XML into an `XmlDocument` and remove it, just stop it being written in the first place using `XmlWriterSettings`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    // ...
};
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t9E9Vo) for a working demo.